# JQuery postback doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I've a function like this;

```
    <script type="text/javascript">            
        function callUrl(url) {       
            $.post(url);
            alert('You'll redirect a telephone');
        }        
    </script>
```

I'm only want to work url. When the url'll worked, the user call a telephone. I'm correctly getting url. But  $.post(url); doesn't work. How do you solve this?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I want to open that url, but the user must not see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a success handler to the $.post method to perform your callbacks.

```
$.post(url, function(data) {
   // Call the phone here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to encode url use encodeURIComponent function

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
        function callUrl(url) {       
            $.post(encodeURIComponent(url));
            alert('You\'ll redirect a telephone');
        }        
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write "success"

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  success: function(){
  alert("");
  }
});
```